# android unit test: clearing prefs before testing activity

Tags: android, testing, junit

I want to ensure that a preference is cleared before my `Activity` is started in my unit test.

The problem is that to clear the preferences, you need to call `getActivity()`.  After that, the `Activity` is started, which reads the preferences.

```
@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    mActivity = this.getActivity();
    SharedPreferences prefs = 
       PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mActivity);
    prefs.edit().clear().commit();
}
```

When `getActivity()` is called, the `Activity` is created, which reads the value of the pref, before the next lines clear the pref.

Is there a way obtaining a `Context` object without starting the `Activity`?

I'm new to Android unit tests, so maybe I'm missing something basic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer here,
[Accessing application context from TestSuite in Setup() before calling getActivity()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544205/accessing-application-context-from-testsuite-in-setup-before-calling-getactivi)

Call,

```
this.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()
```